# using same functional tests across magento websites

Tags: magento-enterprise, testing, automation

We have many different sites developed using magento 1.4. I need to develop functional tests like login, place an order etc, full user journeys for these. I am using test automation framework (taf also known as mtaf) to do so. Even though this is deprecated and doesn't support Magento 1.4, I understand we can build our own testcases on it and not use the pre written test cases. I plan on using selenium with it.

My question is since all magento sites use same cascading style sheets which may include same id s, classes, names etc, can I use the same set of functional tests across websites, since the css selectors used across are the same?

Or Am i totally wrong and its not the same set of selectors used across different magento websites? Is it because each website could be using a different theme and thereby resulting in different selectors?

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the agency I work for we have a collection of [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) tests that we use for mosts webshops. Generally if you stick to, for example, the RWD template for all shops you will have the same selectors.

So, if you use the same template as basis for all shops you should be fine